# request.getParameter() returns null while uploading file

Tags: jsp, servlets, file-upload

I'm trying to save a form info to a mysql database using J2EE and eclipse in Windows 10. I'm having this problem request.getParameter() returns null even though i used the same name in the form. The server shows no errors and I don't know what to do next. Here's my  HTML Code.

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Insert title here</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <center>
    <h1>Don</h1>
        <form method="post" action="Fund" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td> Titre :  </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="titre" size="50"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Cause : </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="cause" size="50"/></td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td> Ammount : </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="ammount" size="50"/></td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td> Story: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="story" size="50"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Photo: </td>
                    <td><input type="file" name="image" size="50"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the Fund.java code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import jakarta.servlet.http.Part;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class Don
 */
@WebServlet("/Fund")
public class Fund extends HttpServlet {
    
    //database connection settings
    
    private String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdb";
    private String dbUser = "root";
    private String dbPass = "root";
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public Fund() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String titre = request.getParameter("titre");
        String cause = request.getParameter("cause");
        String ammount = request.getParameter("ammount");
        String story = request.getParameter("story");
        
        System.out.println(titre);
        
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        
        Part filePart = request.getPart("image");
        
        System.out.println(filePart);
        if(filePart != null) {
            System.out.println("here");
            System.out.println(filePart.getName());
            System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
            System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());
            
            inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
        }
        
        Connection conn = null;
        String message = null;
        
        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver());
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,dbUser,dbPass);
            
            String querySetLimit = "SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=104857600;";  // 10 MB
            Statement stSetLimit = conn.createStatement();
            stSetLimit.execute(querySetLimit);
 
            
            String sql = "INSERT INTO don (title, cause, ammount, story, image) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, titre);
            statement.setString(2, cause);
            statement.setString(3, ammount);
            statement.setString(4, story);
            
            if(inputStream != null) {
                statement.setBlob(5, inputStream);
            }
            
            int row = statement.executeUpdate();
            if(row > 0) {
                message ="File uploaded and saved into database";
            }
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            message = "ERROR: " + e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            request.setAttribute("Message",message);
            
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Message.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }

    }
}
```

Please help me out I don't know what to do thank you

Comment: Check your spelling. Clearly you have misspelt a parameter name omewhere. In this post you have misspelt `ammount` three times, for example. Is this the real code?

Comment: The server does not care about the spelling of a word, as long as it is the same in the posted data and the server code - posting "ammmaound=123" and retrieving is with `request.getParameter("ammmaound")` will work. (This does not mean that spelling is not important, just not apparently the cause of the issue.) @OP: It seems you debugged the server code, is that right? Can you actually see the servlet being invoked? What about the browser console - is the browser actually sending the values you expect? Any special configuration (server, filters, web.xml) that might interfere?

Comment: One more thing: I see you are sending a file in the post; check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47027116/uploading-files-and-getting-parameters-in-java-webservlet) and most importantly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet).

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos The mis-spelling strongly suggests that the OP is careless about spelling, which must be consistent between client and server.

Comment: FYI: the term "J2EE" has been renamed to another term in 2006 and the HTML <center> tag was deprecated in 1998. Please make sure you're using up to date resources to learn web stuff.